# SQL Select statment with remove first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have multiple rows in table, I'm using select statement to fetch the details.

```
select * from pdetails where pcode='P000437'
```

**Result**

[image]

my query print 3 records but I don't want to print first row.

Is there any option to use select statement with condition to count and remove first row.

Comment: You want to remove first row always?

Comment: first row based on what? which column gives us the order?

Comment: How should system identify which is the first row to be deleted and is it based on per pcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this query

```
 SELECT * FROM (
    select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) row,* from pdetails where pcode='P000437'
    )t
    WHERE row != 1;
```

Comment: also changed Date to id :D

Comment: it is not copy when you are use order by date. that date sorting and remove first record

Comment: Getting the result with both, data and id then what is the difference in this answer

Comment: i assume that id is primary key. and order by function to read,,,,

Comment: @skgacharya - This answer will remove the row with the minimum `id`. My solution will remove the row with the minimum `date`. Results will be different when order or `id` mismatches the `date`. Use the one which is closer to your exact requirement which we do not know

Answer (score 3):

Try this statement

```
 select * from pdetails where pcode='P000437' 
    order by id
    OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Although correct for SQL Server 2012+, the question is specifically tagged SQL Server 2008, which does not support this syntax.

Comment: No one restricted to give answer for sql-server2012

Comment: This answer did not deserve the down vote, in my opinion.  However, the answerer might consider *deleting* it, because it is not for the right version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this using a Temp Table,

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) as ROWID into #temp FROM pdetails 
WHERE pcode='P000437'

SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE ROWID != 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * 
from pdetails 
where pcode= 'P000437' AND ID <> (SELECT MIN(ID)
                                 FROM pdetails
                                 WHERE pcode= 'P000437')
```

Comment: I got the result but not understanding the query keep it simple

Comment: @skgacharya In the subquery I'm extract the MinValue of ID according to your filter. So I exclude from the principal query that value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to exclude the first row (based on `Date`)

Something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM (
select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Date ASC)rn,* from pdetails where pcode='P000437'
)t
WHERE rn != 1;
```